# Angular 2: ng build --prod errors while ng serve run without erros

Tags: angular, heroku

I tried to deploy my angular 2 app to heroku, but when I try to build for production, a long list of error appears. I should mention, that on ng serve, the app is running without problems and errors.
[The list of errors is showed in attached photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YCdEU.jpg)

I'm cannot find any solution for this problems. All main modules are updated to latest version. Thank you

Comment: Make sure that component properties you access from the template are `public`.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that if you were to run ng-serve --prod you would get the same errors. When you don't specify --prod many different errors are ignored.

For instance without --prod it will compile and not warn you that properties are referencing are not mentioned on the type you specified. Now if you went and changed that object type to type any the errors would then go away.

Without your errors being listed here I am sure many of them are simple errors like above. You may need to go back and update your types to ensure any properties you reference in *.ts or *.html files are added to the class definition.

Answer (score 0):

The first couple of lines are related to the fact that your property/method `_centerMap` is set as `private`. If you want to use a property/method in the template, it needs to be `public` (I am not sure about `protected`).

The lines `Property X does not exist on type 'Object'` is most likely related to your types. I think the type checking is more strict when you build for production compared to serving a development server. I assume somewhere in your code you have an object with properties and it looks something like this:

```
public myObject: Object = {
    fillColor: 'someValue',
    // other properties
};
```

In that case the type checking fails because those properties are not defined on the default `Object`. To fix that error, either remove the type all together or change it to something like this:

```
public myObject: { fillColor: string } = {
    fillColor: 'someValue',
    // other properties
};
```

In case you have a lot of properties in that object, I would suggest creating an `Interface`.

```
export default interface MyObject {
    fillColor: string;
}
```

Which you could use like this:

```
import MyObject from '/path/to/the/interface';

public myObject: MyObject = {
    fillColor: 'someValue',
    // other properties
};
```

The `Property 'height' is private ...` error is the same problem as you first couple of lines - property/method is set as `private` instead of `public`. The problem is just in a different file.

Comment: you were completely right! The answer offered by you solve my issue. Firstly, I thought that this errors are related to some incompatibilities between modules, because errors don't appear some changes and not when I use ng serve. Later, I understand that ng serve skip some "production mode" errors and let the application run. Thank you and I hope that your answer, also, help others